# JPA How add unique contraint on column for @OneToMany relation like on username

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a Class `Site` that represents a website and a Class `User`. A `Site` can have multiple `User`s.

```
class Site {

    private int site_ID;

    @OneToMany // with a join table
    private List<User> users;
    // ...
}

class User {

    private int user_ID;

    private String name;

    private String lastname;

    private String username;

    private String password;

}
```

I want to allow same username to exist on all Sites, but only one by site.

```
Site/User/username
1   /1   /username1
1   /2   /username2
2   /3   /username1
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let the user have a `Site` reference:

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
private Site site;
```

Now add the constraint to user:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "username", "site" })})
@Entity
public class User{
// etc
}
```

You will also have to change the `Site` mapping:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="site")
private List<User> users;
```

Comment: The OP said he wanted to use a join table for his OneToMany. Moreover, even if he wanted a foreign key, your unique constraint isn't useful since id is already unique (which guarantees that id/site will always be)

Comment: @JB Nizet: a) sure, he thinks a join table is the right thing to do, but I am suggesting not to use one (it doesn't seem to make any sense in this case) b) that was my error, I meant username, not user_id (fixed)

Comment: Thks, I,ll try that tonight.  So if I want to do that, I need to keep a reference to Site in my User object ?  At first, I wanted to keep the children not knowing there parent, I know I'm a bad person.

Comment: @Sebastien I can understand you approach, but it has drawbacks. For one thing, a join table is one more table that needs to be included in the generated sql statements.

Answer (score 9):

By default, the primary index on the join table is unique and based on the site and user FK
So, you cannot have the same user with the same site duplicated.

But if you want to force a constraint :

```
class Site {

    private int site_ID;

    @OneToMany // with a join table
    @JoinTable(
        uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"Site_ID","users_ID"})
    )
    private List<User> users;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check `@UniqueConstraint` . It allows defining any unique constraint