# Duplicate data from JPA query (sql constraint)

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

For some reason I'm returning 9 rows of duplicate data using this query in my repository.

```
 @Query("select distinct profile from OfficeProfile profile where profile.fcoDesignCd in 
(select officeLocation.asccode from OfficeLocation officeLocation, OfficeProfile profile 
where officeLocation.statecode = :stateCode and officeLocation.asccode = profile.fcoDesignCd)")     
    public List<OfficeProfile> searchStateASC(@Param("stateCode") String stateCode);
```

The sql query that returns 9 distinct rows of data is below.  The queries appear to be identical.

```
select
op.FCO_DESIGN_CD,
op.office_addr_line1,
op.office_addr_line2,
op.office_addr_state,
op.office_addr_zip
from cridba.office_profile op
where op.fco_design_cd in  (
select asc_code from cridba.cris_lk_location cll , cridba.office_profile op
where cll.state_code='VA'
and cll.asc_code = op.fco_design_cd);
```

This is how I'm iterating over the values.  I set my debugger and noticed the same 9 values with ids.

```
for(OfficeProfile locationInfo: officeLocatorRepository.searchStateASC(stateCode))
```

Here are my entity relationships.
Office Profile (Parent)

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "profile")
private Set<OfficeLocation> officeLocation = new HashSet<>(0);
```

Office Location (Child)

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "asc_code", referencedColumnName = "fco_design_cd", nullable = false, insertable=false, 
updatable=false)
public OfficeProfile profile;
```

I'm overriding equals and hashcode in both classes.  Since I'm joining these tables using asc_code do i override that or id? or both?  Here is what I have so far.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    OfficeProfile officeProfile = (OfficeProfile) o;
    if (officeProfile.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(getId(), officeProfile.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getId());
}
```

Should I add @Id to fcoDesignCd even though this table already has an id?  fcoDesignCd is the referenced column in join?

```
@Column(name = "fco_design_cd")
private String fcoDesignCd;
```

HQL output...

```
select distinct officeprof0_.office_type_id as office_type_id1_1_, ......
from cridba.office_profile officeprof0_ where officeprof0_.fco_design_cd in 
(select officeloca1_.asc_code 
from cridba.cris_lk_location officeloca1_, cridba.office_profile 
officeprof2_ where officeloca1_.state_code=? and 
officeloca1_.asc_code=officeprof2_.fco_design_cd)
```

Does this look like the right path to take?  [JPA How add unique contraint on column for @OneToMany relation like on username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260895/jpa-how-add-unique-contraint-on-column-for-onetomany-relation-like-on-username)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add another @Id column for your table, since you already have one. Make sure that its backed up with a unique constraint in the database.

The overriding of hashCode and equals looks ok also.

The problem with duplicates is probably in the query.